# Converting Arduino port manipulation to ESP32

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I have some code written for Arduino that I am trying to convert to run on my ESP32. It uses direct port manipulation (something I'm not too familiar with). As I understand it I should be using GPIO_OUT_REG  and GPIO_OUT1_REG. My issue is I don't entirely understand what the Arduino code is doing. The code is below:

```
#define CLR_RS    (PORTB &= ~(0x01))
#define SET_RS    (PORTB |=  (0x01))
#define CLR_RESET (PORTB &= ~(0x02))
#define SET_RESET (PORTB |=  (0x02))
#define CLR_CS    (PORTB &= ~(0x04))
#define SET_CS    (PORTB |=  (0x04))
#define CLR_MOSI  (PORTB &= ~(0x08))
#define SET_MOSI  (PORTB |=  (0x08))
#define CLR_SCK   (PORTB &= ~(0x20))
#define SET_SCK   (PORTB |=  (0x20))
```

Is the first line equivalent to all pins in the B data register that are not pin 1?

Comment: The `CLR_*` macros clear the given bit while the `SET_*` ones set that bit.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp. So would the equivalent ESP32 code look like this:


`#define CLR_RS        REG_WRITE(GPIO_OUT_W1TC_REG, BIT1)`

Comment: these are SPI pins. use the SPI library bundled with the esp32 Arduino boards support package for SPI communication